# Check if the service is alive in Jboss

Tags: java, jboss

I have a situation where I have several services deployed on the Jboss (AS). There is a way to check if a service is alive. I'm question myself if the service could be "out-of-date" or "frozen" because some reason and then the client executes the service that isn't working.

There are anything in jboss that will lookup for the "health" of the service?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this would be handled with a "heartbeat" service that you can poll from your client (if you don't get a response, then your service is down). But you could also setup a monitoring tool (there's a number of tools for monitoring java application servers, and you can set them up to send automated emails to warn if your thresholds are exceeded, etc), or  you could monitor your application server through JMX.

Here is a link to the jboss documentation: [jboss JMX](https://thenewcircle.com/bookshelf/jboss_admin_tutorial/jmx.html)
and a link to a tutorial that might get you started [jboss admin tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/monitoring.html)

Comment: Ok thanks. Then I've another question...
How can I monitor the availabilty of a Web Service in jBoss by using JMX.... (I think this question is became more practical).
Thanks in advance.